# Why is multi-threading slower in this implementation?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, gil, pandas.excelwriter

I am connecting to a local database and fetching 500,000 rows from five different tables, (100,000 each). I am `multi-threading` and using the `SQLAlchemy` connection pool. Each thread uses a connection from the pool. In each thread, I am also using `pandas` to dump the data into an excel sheet. So, there would be five worksheets in an excel file.

For this, it is taking around `7 - 8` minutes. I then tried to do the same thing sequentially. It took a minute less.

I want to know what is going on here. I thought `multi-threading` would be much faster. Is it because of the `GIL`? Am I doing it the wrong way? Are there any better way of doing the same thing?

```py
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:

    with cf.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        try:
            stats = [executor.submit(query_write, cnx_pool.connect(), writer, table) for table in tables]
        except (excp.OperationalError, excp.TimeoutError) as e:
            print(f'\nError connecting to the database:\n{e._message}\n')
        else:
            for stat in cf.as_completed(stats):
                print(stat.result())
```

```py
def query_write(cnx, writer, table):
    query = f'SELECT * FROM {table} LIMIT 100000'

    try:
        table_data = pd.read_sql(query, cnx)
    except excp.ProgrammingError as e:
        print(f'\nError occured:\n{e.orig}\n')
        pd.DataFrame().to_excel(writer, sheet_name=table, index=False)
    else:
        table_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=table, index=False)
    finally:
        cnx.close()
```

Comment: I would say that the main bottleneck in your algorithm is the data exchange with the database. Hence, communicating "from multiple angles" with this database will not get rid of this bottleneck, and maybe (as you are experiencing it) even decrease the performance due to the multiple connections. How large is the amount of data being transferred? Maybe you are limited by network speed?

Comment: The exchange with the database is not the bottleneck. It looks like the overhead is causing the issue. I'm not sure.